# How to automatize function output based on Dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas

I've done a simple frequent itemsets analysis in Python. Until now I've just been analyzing all transaction (my data is comprised by transactions across countries). Example below:

```
ReceiptCode         ItemCategoryName
0000P85071000028501 Stationery  
0000P85071000028501 Food        
0000P85071000028501 Hobby       
0000P85071000028501 Kitchen     
0000P85071000028501 Stationery  
0000P85071000028501 Painting
```

I'm running some of the following operations to my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

## Query Data into dataframe
dataset = pd.read_sql_query("""some query""", cnxn)
## Transformations 
dataset_tx = dataset.groupby(['ReceiptCode'])['ItemCategoryName'].apply(list).values.tolist()
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset_tx).transform(dataset_tx)
df = pd.SparseDataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.009, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.3)
```

But I would like to do this analysis across countries, so I add a 3rd column with the country name (example below).

```
ReceiptCode         ItemCategoryName StoreCountryName
0000P85071000028501 Stationery       Ireland
0000P85071000028501 Food             Ireland
0000P85071000028501 Hobby            Ireland
0000P85071000028501 Kitchen          Ireland
0000P85071000028501 Stationery       Ireland
0000P85071000028501 Painting         Ireland
```

Instead of repeating the above steps for all the countries, I'm trying to cram this into a loop, and naming all the variables accordingly, so I can tell the difference between the countries. **That is, I'm trying to get country-specific** `frequent_itemsets` **and** `rules` **variables without doing it manually.** I.e. `rules_Ireland` and `frequent_itemsets_Ireland`.

So far I've grouped the countries in a DataFrameGroup and then lists using

```
g = dataset.groupby('StoreCountryName')
dfs = [group for _,group in g]
```

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here. If I loop over all `dfs[i]` and create transactional lists, I don't know how to keep track of the country name. Does anyone have a solution for this? Or did I approach this completely wrong?

Comment: What is number of rows? Is performance important?

Comment: The plan is to have this update during weekends, so performance is not critical. The raw data import in `dataset` is approx. 14m rows. Right now the maximum row count of the country-grouped DataFrames is 4,5m.

Comment: @jezrael Updated the question, as I realized it might not have been specific enough.

Comment: Unfortuantely if not working answer is deleted, no idea how proccessing.